# Passing Integer To Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Getting an NumberFormat exception from a form submission that passes a phone number. However, the number passed is in fact a number and I convert it to an int within the servlet. Within the error message you can see that an int was entered in - 8456640236.

**Servlet Method**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    Contact newComment = new Contact();

    newComment.setName(request.getParameter("nameParameter"));
    newComment.setEmail(request.getParameter("emailParameter"));
    newComment.setPhone(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("phoneParameter")));
    newComment.setComment(request.getParameter("commentParameter"));

    request.setAttribute("commentAttribute", newComment);

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/successComment.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

**Error Message**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8456640236"
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:461)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
org.test.Servlet.doPost(Servlet.java:21)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: Looks like you need a Long for that value.

Comment: Phone numbers shouldn't be regarded as numbers.  They're numeric strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value you're trying to parse is larger than an `Integer` can hold, [2<sup>31</sup>-1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE), which is 2147483647.

You'd need to make it a `Long` (or `long`) instead and use [`Long#parseLong()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) to parse it.

```
newComment.setPhone(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("phoneParameter")));
```

Note that this concrete problem has **nothing** to do with JSP/Servlets, but anything with [basic Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). You'd have exactly the same problem when doing so in a plain vanilla Java class with a `main()` method and hardcoded values (which would have been easier for you to isolate the problem).

Comment: thank you for your help. and yes it is obvious now knowing the solution that my problem did not have to do with jsp's and servlets. but when i was staring at the screen wondering wtf was going on and trying countless things to fix it it was not so obvious.

Comment: Nothing personally, just a hint for the next time. Try to invest some more time in isolating the concrete problem in a plain vanilla Java class.

Answer (score 1):

8456640236 can not be converted to a 32 bit integer, it's hex representation is 0x1 F80E 16EC

If it's a phone number, why not just keep it as a String?  What's to stop users entering it as "+44 12 3456 7890" or "1800 DONT CALL ME"

Comment: @gmustudent - _Always_ validate server-side even if you have client-side JS validations. Users can bypass JS validation.

Answer (score 0):

8456640236 is too big for a 32 bit int. Try treating it as a long instead of an int.

Answer (score 0):

On a lighter note, I would recommend to use String instead of int/long for phone numbers. Reason for that being, some users prefer to enter phone numbers separated by "-" and also if in future you intend to ask user to enter ISD code and std codes also along with phone numbers, you will have to support more lengthy numbers and then you might end up being at wrong side of the data type. Also, when prompting the user to enter ISD code, users tend to prefix that by "+".

Though For this you will have to check your project requirements.

Hope that helps.